# How it possible given string belong to given grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Consider this context-free grammar:

$$G:\\\;\; S\to aSbb|aaSbbb|\lambda$$

Is the string $a^{2020} b^{4020}\in L(G)$?

I try to derive such a string but I can't, how it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, provided there is a solution in nonnegative integers to the following pair of equations.

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcrc@{\qquad}l}
x  & + &  2y    &   =   &  2020 \\
2x & + &  3y    &   =   &  4020
\end{array}
\right.
$$